# How to parse unquoted numeric json values in java?

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, gson

How to parse numeric unquoted values?
Actually, I see only the option to parse using regex and wrap digit values into quotes. Is it possible to parse that in another way? Thanks for your time.

```
{
  "field1":"Some string value",
  "field2": 0.5,
  "field3":3
}
```

My DTO class:

```
public class MyDTO{
    @JsonProperty("field1")
    private String field1;

    @JsonProperty("field2")
    private Float field2;

    @JsonProperty("field3")
    private Integer field3;

    //getters, setters
}
```

Comment: That is just regular JSON. Numbers look like that. Any JSON library will be able to parse it.

Comment: but when I try to convert to object - it doesn't work except first attribute

Comment: what do you mean by "when I try to convert to object"?

Comment: I mean, deserealization when use:
gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyDTO.class);

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this problem. What I did was 1. Copy your DTO class to a new file, 2. Write a driver that calls `gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyDTO.class);` with the JSON you include, and prints out each field in the file, 3. Build it with gson-2.8.6 and jackson-annotations-2.10.0, 4. Run it and see each field being populated just fine. How do I reproduce this?

Comment: "Doesn't work except first attribute" -- It works as regular JSON just like all the others tell you, and not how you imagine it would work, right? Why do you think that JSON number literals must be enclosed in `"` and what made you think it? Next, if it "doesn't" work like you want it to, why not post an error you're getting not making anybody else waste their time trying to guess if you really encountering a real issue or you haven't read the JSON basics? Why have you tagged it with both Gson and Jackson?  Too many why's. Downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You mention Gson. To parse the above String with Gson you would do the following:

```
String jsonString = "{...}";
JsonObject result = JsonParser.parseString(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
```

There is nothing special about unquoted numeric values. All the JSON parsing libraries will support that.

Comment: just tried this way, when converted to string back - it also has digit values without quotes that don't possible to convert to my dto object.

I see, that I can use json.get("key") - but this is not for my case, since the real json is much larger and has a more complex structure

Comment: I am sorry I don't quite understand what you are saying.

Comment: oh sorry :) will edit

Comment: In result of convertation this JsonObject I still have no quotes for digit types that I don't possible to parse to my DTO.
 In your case, I see, that I can use gson.get("key") - but I need to do that for the multiple values

Comment: try MyDTO result = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyDTO.class);